# Parsing a data file with Pandas where headers may change position

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multidimensional-array

I have to write a parser for a data file we use at work. I chose Pandas because I've read it's pretty fast and performance is a big focus with it. As a side note, I have never used Pandas before today.

As I understand it, I need to tell Pandas where my headers line is in CSV-like file. But the files at work may have variable numbers of lines before the actual data starts.

Example:

```
Software :SomeCorpSoft 2.3.4
Measurement Name;default
Created;2017-11-30T11:42:09Z
Scan Type;Threshold scan
Serial Number;A-SERIAL-NUM-1234
Sensor Nickname;
Trend Count;1
Trigger Level;0
Trigger Holdoff;0
start;0
end ;0

F1; 44.12; H; 8;
Time;F1 ;V 1 ;Hp 1 ;C 1 ;P 1 ;V 2 ;Hp 2 ;C 2 ;P 2 ;V 3 ;Hp 3 ;C 3 ;P 3 ;V 4 ;Hp 4 ;C 4 ;P 4 ;V 5 ;Hp 5 ;C 5 ;P 5 ;V 6 ;Hp 6 ;C 6 ;P 6 ;V 7 ;Hp 7 ;C 7 ;P 7 ;V 8 ;Hp 8 ;C 8 ;P 8 ;
0;13.448671;349.458099365;0;7.72320135575;-105.609801195;8.54580983665;-15.5168133183;0.0477259658688;101.686749515;4.46981738574;152.711715748;0.0728701513916;77.1428145399;17.8438225472;-163.940792731;0.95931622744;48.4915601658;0.525170185762;-85.3977558257;0.255517896038;-58.4781138655;2.0410204213;131.266863348;0.291022526301;-145.942080277;12.7706899744;-150.335793306;1.3724642398;-161.919972567;5.3790623792;-148.609825665;0.512542366745;-177.811876518;
```

So in this example, my actual headers are on line 14 (13 if it ignores empty lines, not sure about that), where it starts with **Time** (this is a constant, so maybe some lambda way to take that into account?)

But I also need the previous lines, to form different objects in the database ("**Created;**" gives me the time of the measurement, for instance).

I then have to create object instances for each of the headers. They do align with the data below, so for instance:

```
Time -> 0
F1 -> 13.448671
V1 -> 349.458099365
... so on...
```

So I have

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_dir)
for i in df.values:
    for x in i:
        if "Software" in x:
            software_ver = x.split(':')[1]
        if "Time" in x:
            headers = x
```

But that feels "cheap"? There's probably a Pandas way to do it. After that, I was planning on doing a zip for each line after the headers, as they all match, so that I can pair the values with the header, but again, probably a better way to do it, that is more efficient.

The files can have a couple hundred thousand lines, and I have to create one object instance for each header element of each line. The current parser we have takes a few minutes for this, but I need to bring that time way way down.

Comment: Does the `skiprows` help maybe? Something like `pd.read_csv(file_dir, skiprows=13)`

Comment: I read about about skiprows, but my main issue is that the 13 may sometimes be 10, or 9, or 17, etc. And I also need the information before the headers, so probably don't want to skip it?

Comment: What does Pandas have to do with this? Aren’t you trying to write a parser? Pandas can read CSV, yes, but that data is going to need to be parsed and cleaned beforehand.

Comment: The parsing of the file is the first step, sure, but then I have to do a lot with the resulting CSV-like output of the parsing. And I need something that is capable of quickly processing large amounts of data in a 2D array structure. I thought Pandas was the go-to for that?

If needed, I can parse and prepare the data with something else, and then pass the cleaned 2D array to Pandas. I just thought Pandas had a robust parsing side to it that could handle my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is **not** a parser. It is a wonderful library when it comes to data processing, and it provides some parsers for simple data formats. This file format cannot be parsed with Pandas, at least not simply and probably not efficiently.

Whether pandas will be relevant depends of what processing you want to do after. If you intend to be able to do mid complexity operations it may be. If you only need to feed a database table forget it.

If high performance is required, you should probably forget Python too. It is indeed an excellent language and I really love programming in Python. But if the requirement is just to parse the file as quickly as possible, I would use C. And if a database is involved, the part that has to be optimized first is not the file parsing but the database accesses.

Said differently, it is like driving a screw with a hammer. In the end the screw will be inside the board, and if you only have a hammer it may be the solution. But using a screwdriver would be better...

Comment: Well, the project is a website, running on Django, with a PostgreSQL database. I have used Cython before a little, but my thing is definitely not C. Which is why I'm using Python. The user uploads a file and I have to parse it, and create objects out of so that I can bulk insert through Django into the DB.

What approach would you take in such a scenario? I'm not dead set on Pandas, but I thought it'd be my fastest option.

Comment: Pandas is memory consuming. Does not look great for a multi-user website. I better understand why Python is required, so I would profile direct parsing (`split`) vs the `csv` module. I would also try to by-pass Django and directly insert into the DB. But maybe the best option is to accept the thing to be time consuming and just do bht processing in the background. I can hardly say more: it is really an architectural choice. If memory is not a problem in your specific use case, pandas might be useful. I justed warned you that it is not an all purpose magic bullet...